# How can I find the DHCP server address in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: router, ip, dhcp, ubuntu-18.04, dhcp-server

I need to know the DHCP server IP address.

How can I find the DHCP server address in the network from my Ubuntu 18.04 device?

Answer (score 0):

First you should install `net-tools` if you don't have them:

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

Then, you can run `ifconfig` to figure out which interface you are using. After that, you have to run

```
sudo dhclient -d -nw -4 name_of_your_interface
```

There is an sample output, my interface is `eth0`:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/0a:00:29:4c:3e:67
```

Comment: Where is the IP in you output? I can not see it. also I tried your steps but there is no explicit DHCP IP.

Comment: add -4 to your command.